# How to pass a variable selector to jquery .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

This is the scenario. In a jQuery DataTable I have some value and an edit button to modify 2 of them; clicking on it, a modal popup is opened and offer a form to insert the new value for notes and status:

...

```
"columnDefs": [
                        {
                           "targets": [ 0 ],
                           "visible": false
                           //"searchable": false
                        }],

                "columns":  [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "date" },
                    { "data": "type" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "user_name" },
                    { "data": "status" },
                    { "data": "closing_date" },
                    { "data": "info" },
                    { "data": "note" },
                    { "data": null,
                          "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {

                            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' id=\'" + full.id + "\' data-toggle='modal' data-id=\'" + full.id + "\' data-target='#myModal'> Edit </button>";

                      }
```

...

Immediately below, I have the ajax function to send the inserted value to a Spring controller:

```
//This function is used to send the form data to Spring controller; cause we use a modal, with code that must be put in the file with html table head,
    //we must replace the use of view made by jsp using an ajax function
    $('#myModal').on('click', '.btn.btn-success', function(event) {
        var form = $('#updateeventsform'); //recover the form inside modal by using id
        var formdata = form.serializeObject(); //use the serializeObject function to prepare data for Json format
        formdata.idevent = $(this).attr('data-id'); //add the event id to form data, after setting it with the IDnumber variabile
        console.log(formdata, this);
        event.preventDefault();

        //here starts the code to sending data to Spring controller
        $.ajax({
                url: "../updateevents.json",
                type: "post",
                data: formdata,
                success : function() {

                    console.log("Invio riuscito.");
                    DTevents.ajax.reload( null, false ); //we reload the table, showing immediately the data updated.
                }

            });

        });
```

This code give me an undefined value on formdata.idevent; and it's right, because the `$(this)` value refers to the current element (in my case, the submit button). 
As you can see, the id for the button is a numeric value, setted with the `full.id` field. 
So, I've got a try: put a numeric value as selector for `attr()` function. I changed:

```
formdata.idevent = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

in

```
formdata.idevent = $('#5').attr('data-id');
```

and this works.

So, the question is: is there a way to use a variable value as `selector` for the `.attr()` function? If no, what should I use to pass the correct value to the controller?

Edit for comment answer.

Already used $(this).data('id'); does not works. I got undefined values for idevent.

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-md' **id=\'" + full.id +**
```

here you can note the numeric id of button element.

The intent is: this table represent events. When the 2 fields modified, notes and status, must be send to the controller, i Must send also the events id to it and i want perform this with the use of `.attr()` function.
Now, this function must be used on a selector; i may want use the button id as selector but I have different button with different id. So, if i click the 4th button, the id is 4 and I may have:

```
formdata.idevent = $['#4'].attr('data-id');
```

if I click the 5th button the code must be:

```
formdata.idevent = $['#5'].attr('data-id');
```

if I click the 6th button:

```
formdata.idevent = $['#6'].attr('data-id');
```

and so on. So, I have a variable selector to use; I don't know how to perform this.

Comment: Can't you just format a string as selector? I know a string as variable works as a selector (e.g. #test_1)

Comment: try to use `$(this).data('id');`. Also in your example `$(this)` refers to `#myModal` and not to `#5`

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but it looks like you want:  `var sel = "#5"; var id = $(sel).data("id");`

Comment: "*As you can see, the id for the button is a numeric value*" - I can't see this in your code as provided.

Comment: @SchalkKeun yes, that's the issue.  OP knows how to use `$(this)` but `this` is the modal, not the id they want.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add an hidden input to the modal...

```
<input type="hidden" id="idevent" name="idevent">
```

And on a "Edit" button click, carry its `id` to the modal `form`:

```
$(".btn.btn-info").on("click",function(){
  var idevent = $(this).data("id");    // Or $(this).attr("id")

  // Delay for the modal openning animation...
  setTimout(function(idevent){
    $('#myModal form #idevent').val(idevent);
  },800);
});
```

Then, the info would already be in the form when user submits it.
;)